# Extract tar.gz file to a directory and create the directory if not exist

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I know that I can run

```bsh
$ tar xf somefile.tar.gz -C somedir
```

to extract the tar.gz file to somedir, but it requires somedir exists first.

Is there a way to extract to a directory and create the directory on the fly if it does not exist?

Comment: Perhaps: `mkdir -p somedir && tar xf somefile.tar.gz -C somedir` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the GNU `tar` command, you can do this:

```
tar -xf somefile.tar.gz --one-top-level=somedir
```

From `man 1 tar`:

```
  --one-top-level[=DIR]
       Extract all files into DIR, or, if used without argument, into a subdirectory named
       by  the  base name of the archive (minus standard compression suffixes recognizable
       by --auto-compress).
```